# How to read emails and etheir attachment from .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, email

I have to read incoming emails every x minutes from a mailbox. Currently i am sending emails via hmailserver so presume this will be a good starting point.

If i create a new mailbox sendtome@domain.com (the domain is all ready set up with rdns etc) is there an easy way to read the email and its attachment from .net 4 (i have never read emails from code before so no ideas here).

I was thinking of having a windows service running that checks the mailbox every 5 minutes and can read and process emails and their csv attachments.

Any help and suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a script once that had to do just what you wanted.

Sadly there aren't any default functions in .NET (as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong), so we had to go to an external library. We use the freeware [OpenPOP library](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/).

Retrieving the messages is done with the following function:

```
Private Function GetMails(ByVal hostname As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal useSsl As Boolean, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message)
        Dim client As OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client = New OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client()
        client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl)
        client.Authenticate(username, password)

        Dim messageCount As Integer = client.GetMessageCount()

        Dim allMessages As List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message) = New List(Of OpenPop.Mime.Message)(messageCount)

        For count As Integer = 1 To messageCount
            Try
                allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(count))
            Catch ex As OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.PopServerException
                allMessages.Add(Nothing)
            End Try
        Next
        Return allMessages
    End Function
```

All that's left now is to read the mail messages and use standard IO techniques to store their attachments.

More info on the classes used should be found in the OpenPOP project I linked.

Comment: FoxHound thanks for this. I will look into the OpenPop as a starter.

did you use a windows service in order to do all this like i am thinking of doing?

Comment: It was a console script with a scheduler we're using, but this basic code should be usable in any kind of project.

Comment: thanks. any benefit doing this as a console script over a windows servive - i never even thought of a console script.

Comment: I don't have much experience with windows services, so I do not know what the benefits are for one over the other.

It was just requested to make it as a script at the time.

BTW, since it seemed to help you, could you mark the answer as such?

Comment: ok thankyou. I think i may go for a console application after a little bit of research. As i can change the schedule easily. I will look more into the email stuff and post  and further questions. If you have any fursther scripts or helpful information please post. Thanks again

Comment: Something useful to know is that the OpenPop.Mime.Message object contains a ToMailMessage() function to convert the message to a default System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object. I assume you're familiar with that class.